# ImageResizer adding gAMA and sRGB in png

Tags: imageresizer

We are using ImageResizer to resize the image on server side. But with some png image it will insert some meta data called gAMA and sRGB, it will cause color issue in output image. Is there a way to get rid of that?

[image]

Comment: Spec says that sRGB chunk requires fallback (not the same) cHRM and gAMA chunks. As for how to remome: use pngcrush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageResizer uses the Windows API to encode PNG and Jpeg images. Very little control is offered through this API, so there's actually no way to fix that, and it can vary with Windows version.

Thus, we are putting our development effort into [a new platform, Imageflow](https://www.imageflow.io/imageresizer), where we can actually control the codecs that are involved. Color management is just one of many things that we can finally do right. Given that Imageflow is a ground-up rewrite, we [crowdfunded a portion of the development](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/njones/imageflow-respect-the-pixels-a-secure-alt-to-image) (19 hours left).